Azure Devops REST API - publish build artefacts from local
I'm trying to publish some files as build artefacts in an Azure DevOps build pipeline with PowerShell using this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2#artifactresource
My powershell looks like this:
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/<org>/<project>/_apis/build/builds/<buildId>/artifacts?api-version=7.2-preview.5"

$body = @{
  name = 'testpublish'
  resource = @{
    data = "./testfolder/*"
    type = "filepath"
  }
}

$headers = @{
  'Authorization' = "Basic " + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":<pat>"))
  'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $body

however, I'm getting error:
Invoke-RestMethod:
{
  "$id": "1",
  "innerException": null,
  "message": "TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred.",
  "typeName": "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException, Newtonsoft.Json",
  "typeKey": "JsonReaderException",
  "errorCode": 0,
  "eventId": 0
}

Could someone point me to the correct syntax, and let me know if I'm missing anything please?

I can reproduce the same error with your script. You need to convert the $body to json format.
      $body = @{
        name = 'testpublish'
        resource = @{
          data = "./testfolder/*"
          type = "filepath"
        }
      } | ConvertTo-Json

However, the rest api referred is used to associate an artifact with a build, with the script above, the artifact created will not have any content actually as your data are not shared path.

If you are creating build artifact from build pipeline, it's recommended to use existing task PublishPipelineArtifact@1 or PublishBuildArtifacts@1, or logging command:
##vso[artifact.associate type=filepath;artifactname=MyFileShareDrop]\\MyShare\MyDropLocation

If they doesn't meet the requirement, you can use Azure CLI instead, it will have the content in artifact, and the command can also run on local machine.
- powershell: |
    az pipelines runs artifact upload --artifact-name newtestpublish --path "testfolder" --run-id 5995 --org https://dev.azure.com/{orgname} --project {projectname}
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(pat)


From local machine:


It looks like you're trying to upload a folder on the build agent as a pipeline artifact. The error message you're receiving is likely because the type and data inputs aren't correct. However, if you stop and think about this as a REST API where a local machine communicates with a remote server, the backend server won't have any idea what ".\testfolder\*" refers to, so this might not be what you're looking for.
This REST API endpoint would be a good fit if you wanted to link a previous build artifact to a new build, or if you had a zip file hosted somewhere and you wanted to add a link from your build to that downloadable artifact. There are some hints implied in this example usage.
Here are a few better alternatives:

Logging Syntax: your powershell script can emit a special log statement that the build agent is able to process as a file upload command:  ##vso[artifact.upload ...]<file>

Publish Artifact Task: instead of using a PowerShell task to upload the files, use the PublishArtifactTask@1 task
- task: PublishArtifactTask@1
  inputs:
     targetPath: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/testfolder
     artifact: testpublish



If you have your heart set on programmatically using the API, you're going to have to do some digging. Both the Logging Commands and the PublishArtifactTask use internal plugins within the build agent exe. The repositories for this aren't in github, but you can setup a build agent locally and then decompile the Agents.Plugins.dll to see how they're uploading to Azure Storage and using the REST API to associate the artifact with your build.
